# Vanishing Hessian on circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology, vector-analysis, vector-fields, hessian-matrix

I'm looking for examples of smooth functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow [0,\infty[$ such that the determinant of their Hessian matrix does only vanish on the unit circle, i.e.

$$\det \mathsf{H}_f(x,y)=f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y) -  f_{xy}^2(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x^2+y^2=1.$$

What can be said about the overall shape of such a function?

Comment: HINT: Take a critical point in one dimension at $x=1$ and make the function radially symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$ it follows
$$\det \mathsf{H}_f(x,y)=4 g'(x^2 + y^2) (2 (x^2 + y^2) g''(x^2 + y^2) + g'(x^2 + y^2)).$$
Such that this vanishes on a circle iff
$$g'(1)=0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ 2g''(1) + g'(1)=0.$$